# Ubuntu How to setup Multi Dhcp Server

Tags: dhcp

If you have 2 NIC (network Lan card) each connected to different networks:

=> eth0: 192.168.1.0/24

=> eth1: 192.168.2.0/24

I need the Dhcp server to serve the different subnets ip leases ?

How to check the leases ?

Can the two subnets ping each others ?

Answer (score 1):

**First install dhcp package :**

```
sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
```

**Second edit dhcp default interface that should serve dhcp leases :**

sudo  gedit /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server

```
# Defaults for dhcp initscript
# sourced by /etc/init.d/dhcp
# installed at /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server by the maintainer scripts 

#
# This is a POSIX shell fragrmnt 
#

# On what interfaces shauld the [MCP server (dhcpd) serve MCP requests?
#       Separate multiple interfaces with spaces, e.g. "eth0 eth1".
INTERFACES="eth0 eth1"
```

**eth0 and eth1 will serve dhcp**

**Third edit the dhcp conf file to set ranges :**

```
sudo gedit /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

# A slightly different configuration far an internal subnet. 
subnet 192.188.1.6 netmask 255.255.255.0 { 
 range 192.168.1.5 192.168.1.15; 
 option domain-name-servers ns1.domain.org; 
 option domain-name "domain.org";
 option routers 192.168.1.2; 
 option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
 default-lease-time 600;
 max-lease-time 7200; 
}
# A slightly different configuration far an internal subnet. 
subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 { 
 range 192.168.2.5 192.168.2.15;
 option domain-name-servers ns2.domain.org;
 option domain-name "domain2.org";
 option routers 192.168.2.2;
 option broadcast-address 192.168.2.255;
 default-lease-time 600;
 max-lease-time 7200; 
}
```

**Now restart the service :**

```
 sudo service isc-dhcp-server
```

**Dhcp server is active now and the network will be server by the two ranges .**

To make a reservation for a printer example  :

```
host printer1 {
    hardware ethernet 00:1A:6B:6A:2E:0B;
    fixed-address 192.168.1.90;
}


host printer2 {
    hardware ethernet 00:1A:6B:6A:2E:0B;
    fixed-address 192.168.2.90;
}
```

**To check the leases from dhcp server :**

```
gedit /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases
```

**The last question can the two subnets ping each other :**

**Make 192.168.2.* Accessible from 192.168.1.***

Now we need to add a routing entry such that we are able to ping 192.168.2. series

ip-addresses from 192.168.1. series. The common point we have is the GATEWAY machine.

So, on each machine in 192.168.1.* network a default gateway will be added as shown below.

```
route add default gw 192.168.1.2
```

**Now when 192.168.1.5 pings 192.168.2.7, it will go to the GATEWAY via 192.168.1.2.**

In GATEWAY, add the following routing entry.

```
route add -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.2.2
```

Now all the packets addressed to 192.168.2.* network will be forwarded via the

192.168.2.2 interface, which then delivers the packets to the addressed machine.

**Make 192.168.1.* Accessible from 192.168.2.***

It is very similar to what we did earlier.

So, on each machine in 192.168.2.* network a default gateway will be added as shown below.

```
route add default gw 192.168.2.2
```

In GATEWAY, add the following routing entry.

```
route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.2
```

**Now 192.168.2.* machines can ping 192.168.1.* machines.**

Comment: Any reason you are not using code blocks, instead of pictures?

Comment: Parts of this are heavily based on http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/route-examples/

Comment: Please transcribe your images into text, as the majority of the images are screenshots of configuration files. These would benefit from being copy/paste-able and search-able.